# Is it possible to read shapefile field aliases values using fiona?

Tags: python, fiona, fields-attributes

I am using fiona to read a shapefile, but not sure about how to get field aliases. Is this possible using this great library?

Comment: Shapefiles don't have field aliases.  GIS software can generate documents which contain aliases, but you'd have to specify which software in the question.

Comment: Ahh ok, that was my worry, obviously I'm coming from an ArcGIS background.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no SQL-ish `select field as alias` feature in Fiona. Fiona maps a shapefile's schema to a Python dict and dicts have exactly one key per value. *But* you can sort of alias by binding new Python names to key values.

```
>>> a = {'long long key': 1}
>>> a['long long key']
>>> mykey = 'long long key'
>>> a[mykey]
1
```

That's as close as you can get.